# A GridColumn having columnEdit set as RepositoryItemComboBox , on changing SelectedItem, Old Item persists

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

A **gridCoumn** is defined in a Devex Xtra GridControl(winform type).

This column has two properties set :

1. **FieldName** --> a field name of a column in dataSource. **OptionType**
2. **ColumnEdit** --> as a **RepositoryItemCombobox** object , this object's '**Items**' properties is having two value : Option1 , option2 & option3.

When data is set at runtime , the GridColumn shows the respective values in 'OptionType' column.

But now i cant change the values in any combobox of this column to other option by using the dropDown.
What am i missing ?????